# Casting an obj to a generic F# interface

Tags: interface, f#, sequences

I'm trying to cast an object to a generic interface that looks something like
this.

```
type IFetchData<'a> = 
     abstract FetchData: string -> seq<'a>
```

My example usage however looks like the following in FSI:

```
let sample = new Sample()
let box_sample = box(sample) //simulate reflection type that implements interface
let result = unbox<IFetchData<_>>(box_sample) //value restriction
let result2: IFetchData<_> = unbox<IFetchData<_>>(box_sample) //value restriction
```

I'm trying to achieve dynamic invocation of the type member FetchData.
so once I receive type IFetchData<_> then I'd like to invoke the FetchData member with out needing to know what the generic type actually is.

The error that I'm getting is a Value Restriction error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have generic terms just sitting around - but if the compiler can infer a concrete type you are fine.  Alternatively, as the error message states you can convert to a function like this:

```
let result() = unbox<IFetchData<_>>(box_sample)
```

otherwise, you need a concrete type for result like

```
let result2 = unbox<IFetchData<char>>(box_sample)
```

although, here you need to know what you are unboxing to in advance

alternatively, if the code can infer a concrete type later based on your usage you will be fine.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for that. I see now what I need to do to satisfy the compiler. :)